# Records associated to a Kafka batch listener are not consumed for some partitions after several rebalances (resiliency testing)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Some weeks ago my project has been updated to use Kafka 3.2.1 instead of using the one coming with Spring Boot 2.7.3 (3.1.1). We made this upgrade to avoid an issue in Kafka streams – Illegal state and argument exceptions were not ending in the uncaught exception handler.
On the consumer side, we also moved to the cooperative sticky assignator.

In parallel, we started some resiliency tests and we started to have issues with Kafka records that are not consumed anymore on some partitions when using a Kafka batch listener. The issue occurred after several rebalances caused by the test (deployment is done in Kubernetes and we stopped some pods, micro services and broker instances). The issue not present on every listeners. Kafka brokers and micro-services are up and running.

During our investigations,

- we enabled Kafka events and we can clearly see that the consumer is started
- we can see in the logs that the partitions that are not consuming events are assigned.
- debug has been enabled on the KafkaMessageListenerContainer. We see a lot of occurrences of *Receive: 0 records and Commit list: {}*

Is there any blocking points to use Kafka 3.2.1 with Spring Boot/Kafka 2.7.3/2.8.8?

Any help or other advices are more than welcome to progress our investigations.

Comment: I am not aware of any issues when using the 3.2.1 clients with 2.8.x.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the very quick reply. Any ideas why the debug on the KafkaMessageListenerContainer is always showing a number of consumed records equals to 0 and an empty commit list while the consumer lag is quite important? Broker issue? (Spring) Kafka client issue?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that; I tried to reproduce the problem; killing a broker should not cause a rebalance (and does not in my tests), eventually the consumer recovers (switching consumption from another broker instance) and from the expected offset. I even put a breakpoint on the commit; killed the leader node; the commit blocked until the consumer switched to the new leader, and the commit succeeded, with the next record being the correct one.

Comment: A rebalance during a retry is causing the pause which is never resumed. See RetryingBatchErrorHandler#onPartitionsAssigned. The DefaultErrorHandler is used but the internal fallback is reached (the listener does not wrap the business code into a try catch and does not throw a BatchListenerFailedException in case of issue). Multiple listeners are defined, the retry seems to be fired from another listener (shared err handler?). KafkaMessageListenerContainer maintains a list of paused partitions but this list is not updated by the error handler. Spring Kafka bug? Do we need to adapt our listener?

Comment: Shouldn't the KafkaMessageListenerContainer resume all paused partitions and not only the ones contained in the pausedPartitions list? How can the container be aware about the pause made in the error handler? The list is not updated... This may also explain why the container is not firing an application event while it should have?

Comment: May be related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Multiple listeners are defined, the retry seems to be fired from another listener (shared err handler?).

This is a known bug, fixed in the next release:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2382

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/3de1e89ba697ead04de171cfa35273bb0daddbe6

Temporary work around is to give each container its own error handler.

Comment: Very good news. Thanks Gary for the amazing support! Wouldn't it make sense to fire an application event whatever the reason behind the pause/resume? We spent quite a lot of time to understand what was going on...

Comment: Good point; that could be considered another bug - we do publish such events elsewhere. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2387